# CSS animation, fade in background on hover, stay, and go back to previous after a delay

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Lets say I have a HTML element which red with transparency. When I hover the element it should turn a solid red. When I stop hovering the element it should animate back to the first state, but only after X seconds.

So far so good, see code snippet.

My problem is when I stop hovering the element and then go back to hovering it. The initial animation starts again, but it hasn't animation to the initial state hasn't started yet and therefore there is an ugly jump from full colour to transparency and then fade to full colour.

Is there a way to solve this without JavaScript?

Then, by setting the background of the div to the full colour the colour when not hovering is kept. But it also sets it to the initial colour. How can I solve this? Removing it only removes the colour when not hovering!

Opacity with a transition isn't an option as I have content inside this div.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  animation-name: fadeItOut;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: fadeItIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeItIn {
  0% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeItOut {
  0% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 0.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have completely missed the point but why not just do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nwvkzsvw/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have complicated things by using `animation` when a `transition` would have been the better option. Animations have a start and end point (the `0%` and `100%` keyframes) so when you hover-in or out, the element is first set to the state as at the `0%` keyframe (since animation direction is normal) and then proceeds to the `100%` keyframe. When you hover-in or out quickly (before previous animation is complete) you'd always see these jumps because of the setting of `0%` keyframe's props.

The below should be what you need:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 0.3);
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
div:hover {
  background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You got the point pretty well! :) I did try this once before but I have multiple transitions on the same element which killed each other because they where sent in different locations. This helped me find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works.

This "horrible" effect as you said is just because you hover the element before the animation fadeOut finishes.

Try just to reduce the animation delay of the div like that:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  animation-name: fadeItOut;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

This is the fiddle i've made for let you see it: https://jsfiddle.net/oqyep7tt/

At least the Harry's way is way more better than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  transition: background 300ms;
  animation-name: fadeItOut;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: fadeItIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeItIn {
  0% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 0.3);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeItOut {
  0% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(50, 60, 95, 1);
  }
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/rye2gnp3/

Comment: But OP needs the delay to be present before state change on hovering out.

Comment: This one is correct @grinmax and that's exactly the suggestion I had given :)